# Redemption64.dll have nor manifest

Tags: manifest, outlook-redemption

Error Loading: c:\users\tigran\source\repos\voyagerbuild\processor\blocks\Redemption64.dll. Reason: System.BadImageFormatException: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)

How can i create RdoSession with help interop.Redemption? There is this example set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession") but i have not CreateObject method

Comment: please consider to provide much more information about your problem. Use the guidelines of stackoverflow to ask a question.

Comment: Are you attempting to use redemption64.dll as an interop dll? It is not – it is a native COM dll. You need to use interop.redemption.dll (it is bitness agnostic) included with Redemption.